# Erro ao retornar dados usando Fluent NHibernate (Muitos para Muitos)

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, fluent-nhibernate

Tenho uma relação de muitos para muitos (M:M) usando Fluent NHibernate:

**Classe/Map - Unidade:**

```
public class Unidade
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual string Descricao { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<UnidadeGrupo> Grupos { get; set; }

    public Unidade()
    {
        Grupos = new List<UnidadeGrupo>();
    }
}

public class UnidadeMap : ClassMap<Unidade>
{
    public UnidadeMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Assigned();

        Map(x => x.Descricao)
            .Not.Nullable()
            .Length(MapLength.Texto);

        HasManyToMany(x => x.Grupos)
            .Table("UnidadeToGrupo")
            .ParentKeyColumn("Id_Unidade")
            .ChildKeyColumn("Id_UnidadeGrupo");
    }
}
```

**Classe/Map UnidadeGrupo:**

```
public class UnidadeGrupo
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual string Descricao { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<Unidade> Unidades { get; set; }

    public UnidadeGrupo()
    {
        Unidades = new List<Unidade>();
    }
}

public UnidadeGrupoMap()
{
    Id(x => x.Id);

    Map(x => x.Descricao)
        .Not.Nullable()
        .Length(MapLength.Texto);

    HasManyToMany(x => x.Unidades)
        .Table("UnidadeToGrupo")
        .ParentKeyColumn("Id_UnidadeGrupo")
        .ChildKeyColumn("Id_Unidade");
}
```

Estou projetando um Web Service usando Web API. Fiz os testes com inserção e está funcionando corretamente. PORÉM, ao tentar retornar a lista de UnidadeGrupo (GetAll), **ocorre uma exception:**

> "Message": "An error has occurred.",
>   "ExceptionMessage": "The 'ObjectContent`1' type failed to serialize the response body for content type 'application/json; charset=utf-8'.",
>   "ExceptionType": "System.InvalidOperationException",
>   "StackTrace": null,
>   "InnerException": {"Message": "An error has occurred.", "ExceptionMessage": "Self referencing loop detected with type 'RemyWebModel.Entidades.UnidadeGrupo'. Path '[1].Unidades[0].Grupos'.",
>   "ExceptionType": "Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException"

Por que isso acontece e como resolver?

Comment: Coloque o código aonde tal erro acontece?

Answer (score 1):

Após várias pesquisas, entendi o porque do "problema".

Ao gerar os dados N:N, criaria um loop circular infinito, exemplificando:

grupo1: {
   **descricao: "grupo1",**
   unidades: [
      grupos: [
         { **descricao: "grupo1",**
           unidades: [ ... ]
         }
      ]
   ]
}

Ou seja, o grupo lista as unidades, e essa por sua vez, lista seus grupos, e que essa novamente lista unidades, gerando referência circular.

Para resolver, usei o código da thread abaixo:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19664257/why-in-web-api-returning-an-entity-that-has-a-one-to-many-relationship-causes-an